# How to get conda to know where the data and config files of my package are

Tags: python, conda, setup.py

I have created a Python (3.7) package and until now I have been installing and running it in a venv. I want to do the same with Conda, but it seems to not know where my data and configuration files are.

The directory structure looks like:

```
- setup.py
- my_pkg
    + bin
        + my_main.py
        + my_script1.py
        + my_params.py
        + params.json
    + lib
        + utils.py
    + data
        + my_data_file.dat
```

My setup.py includes:

```
scripts = ['my_pkg/bin/my_main.py','my_pkg/bin/my_scripts.py'],
packages = ['my_pkg'],
include_package_data=True
```

Everything works fine when I install in a virtual environment and then run

```
python my_pkg/bin/my_main.py`
```

However, in Conda the environment doesn't know where my params files and data are. The first error I get is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named my_params.py
```

when I do

```
import my_params
```

How do I write the setup.py script so that this will work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look at and use the *setuptools*' *entry points* feature, in particular `console_scripts`. This would allow you to create executable scripts out of the code in the packages.

See [the "Automatic Script Creation" section of the *setuptools*' documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

This is how the whole project could look like:

```
MyProject
├── MANIFEST.in
├── mypackage
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── file.txt
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── __main__.py
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='MyProject',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mymain = mypackage.bin.main:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

`MANIFEST.in`

```
recursive-include mypackage data/*.txt
```

`mypackage/__main__.py`

```
import mypackage.bin.main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mypackage.bin.main.main()
```

`mypackage/bin/main.py`

```
import mypackage.lib.utils

def main():
    mypackage.lib.utils.foo()
```

`mypackage/lib/utils.py`

```
import pkgutil

def foo():
    print(pkgutil.get_data('mypackage', 'data/file.txt').decode())
```

The console script automatically created can then be called as follows:

```
$ mymain
```

Alternatively the package itself is (in a sense) executable, and can be called as follows:

```
$ python3 -m mypackage
```